# how do I get a response/set callback from startService()

Tags: android, android-intent

I've inherited a project and I don't understand how to either get a response, or set a callback from the following code:

```
startService(new Intent(this, VenueUpdateService.class));
```

At the moment the application continues even if the VenueUpdateService fails.  I want to change it so that the application waits for a success/fail from VenueUpdateService.

I get a response within the VenueUpdateService class about success/fail.  But how do I pass this back to the activity that started the service?

Thanks,
James.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I did was change the IntentService to an AsyncTask.

I basically wanted to stop the user interacting with the app while the VenueUpdateService did it's thing as it had to succeed at least once before the user could continue using the app.

So now I have:

```
VenueUpdateTask task = new VenueUpdateTask();
task.execute(response);
```

Within that class I show a progress dialog, do update venues.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking to do seems kind of strange to me. A Service will always succeed in being started if you call startService. It's not as if startService is some risky behavior that needs be wrapped in a try/call block.

But I suppose your Activity could register a BroadcastReceiver that receives a broadcast sent from the service in onStartCommand.

Or maybe you're looking to bind to the service, in which case you'll know when you're bound. [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29)